# Sending an image in whatsapp web using VBA

Tags: vba, whatsapp, sendmessage

Does someone know how to add a picture in an whatsapp web conversation using VBA?
Preferably not as an attachment, but directly in the message.

I've reached a point where the code gets me to open the whatsapp web url, finds the contact to which I want to send the message and places the cursor in the message box, but I couldn't find out yet how to paste the image i've copied or even how to attach a picture inside my machine.

As the image I want to paste and send is a print of some of the worksheet's cells, when I write the code as to make it run "ctrl v" it pastes as a text, not as an image as I want.

My code so far:

```
Sub Send_whats()

Sheets("Current summary").Select

Dim text As String
Dim contact As String

text = "Hi! Here goes a summary of your order"
contact = Cells(6, 3)

If contact = "" Then
MsgBox "Attention, contact is blank!"
Exit Sub
End If

Range("A1:H26").Copy

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Call SendKeys(contact, True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Call SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Call SendKeys("^(V)", True) 'here is where it goes wrong!

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Call SendKeys(text, True)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Call SendKeys("Enter", True)

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Rather than using `SendKeys` (which isn't really reliable) it might be better to look into using a whatsapp API. You should be able to find one which works with VB.Net, in which case it would probably work from VBA with the right references set for the VBA project. Also, [this article](https://whatsmate.github.io/2017-02-04-send-whatsapp-message-vba/) might give you some ideas.